# is it possible php.ini was modified without any manually changes?

Tags: php, linux, centos, php-ini, directadmin

I have CentOs 7 VPS and was installed DirectAdmin on it.

Last night at 03:24 AM php.ini has modified automatically without my interference and I can't find any reason why this happened?!!

It would be highly appreciated if anyone can advise me!

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it's hard to tell what's happened to you, but for example if you have set an automatic update of your package (for example, using cron) it's possible that your php.ini was modified without any manually changes.

Comment: Is it possible to change PHP config files by DirectAdmin while Directadmin is automatically updating? I think Directadmin made this happen!

Comment: I don't know DirectAdmin specifically, what i was pointing out is that this is possible that your php.ini was modified without any manually changes.